# iTunes Review Web Service does not return reviews for some apps

Tags: json, rest, app-store-connect, itunes

I am trying to get customer reviews for some apps using the iTunes web service.
The problem is that I do not receive reviews for some apps.

When I try the following link I receive some reviews:
http://itunes.apple.com/de/rss/customerreviews/id=1163602886/json

However, when I try to get the reviews for Super Mario Run or Facebook, no entries are returned (and there are reviews, obviously):
http://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/id=1145275343/json

A few days ago, everything was fine. Did Apple change anything? Does anyone else have the same problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like they fixed it after couple of days

Comment: That is good news, I have tested the links and reviews are returned.